# Can't launch openresty docker

Tags: nginx, docker, openresty

Trying to launch openresty docker ( https://github.com/3scale/docker-openresty ) on personal Mac and on Docker digitalocean droplet, but get an error:

```
DEBG 'openresty' stderr output:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

**Configs:**

1) Dockerfile

```
FROM 3scale/openresty
ADD openresty.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
ADD . /var/www
CMD ["supervisord"]
```

2) Openresty.conf

```
[program:openresty]
command=/opt/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -p /var/www/ -c config/nginx.conf
autorestart=true
```

3) config/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        default_type text/html;
        content_by_lua '
            ngx.say("<p>hello, world</p>")
        ';
    }
}
}
```

**How I launch it:**

```
docker build -t resty_docker .
docker run resty_docker
```

**Result**:

```
2014-11-02 11:27:01,232 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-11-02 11:27:01,233 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/openresty.conf" during parsing
2014-11-02 11:27:01,233 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cron.conf" during parsing
2014-11-02 11:27:01,233 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/arping.conf" during parsing
2014-11-02 11:27:01,233 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/redis.conf" during parsing
2014-11-02 11:27:01,260 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-11-02 11:27:01,260 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2014-11-02 11:27:01,260 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-11-02 11:27:01,260 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2014-11-02 11:27:02,269 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 7
2014-11-02 11:27:02,272 INFO spawned: 'arping' with pid 8
2014-11-02 11:27:02,275 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 9
2014-11-02 11:27:02,277 INFO spawned: 'openresty' with pid 10
2014-11-02 11:27:02,302 DEBG fd 20 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 34498968 for     <Subprocess at 34067088 with name openresty in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2014-11-02 11:27:02,302 DEBG fd 24 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 34499328 for <Subprocess at 34067088 with name openresty in state STARTING> (stderr)>
2014-11-02 11:27:02,302 INFO exited: openresty (exit status 0; not expected)
2014-11-02 11:27:02,303 DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2014-11-02 11:27:03,306 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-11-02 11:27:03,306 INFO success: arping entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-11-02 11:27:03,306 INFO success: redis entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-11-02 11:27:03,308 INFO spawned: 'openresty' with pid 19
2014-11-02 11:27:03,318 DEBG 'openresty' stderr output:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)

2014-11-02 11:27:03,820 DEBG 'openresty' stderr output:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)

2014-11-02 11:27:04,329 DEBG 'openresty' stderr output:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)

2014-11-02 11:27:04,329 INFO success: openresty entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-11-02 11:27:04,831 DEBG 'openresty' stderr output:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem was not with `ONBUILD CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]`, but with nginx going to background and supervisor killing it.

After adding `daemon off;` to nginx.conf the problem is gone.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that we have updated the readme adding the option you pointed out: https://github.com/3scale/docker-openresty/commit/91e0b5201e207a368e00d292805417e8b2b4aaf8

Answer (score 0):

You parent container [3scale/openresty](https://github.com/3scale/docker-openresty/blob/1.7.2.1/Dockerfile) has the line `ONBUILD CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]` This means that sypervisord is already running (See [here](http://www.tech-d.net/2014/02/06/docker-quicktip-3-onbuild/) for deails of ONBUILD). When your command of supervisord is run it finds the conflict.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. I removed   CMD ["supervisord"] from my Dockerfile, rebuilt docker with    "docker build --no-cache -t resty_docker ." and run it with "docker run resty_docker". Still same error

Comment: Can you add the following command to your docker container:
 netstat -tulpn | grep 8080

Comment: I've added `CMD ["sh", "-c", "netstat", "-tulpn | grep 8080"]` to the end of my Dockerfile (after `EXPOSE`) and here is the output after building and running: `bash-3.2$ docker run resty_docker
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
`